# condition in laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me, I'm trying to validate each row of the row that was highlighted with red in the form using the `validate([])`. If a user filled one of the columns in a row, and try to submit it with the other fields left unfilled, then it will prompt the user that the remaining fields are required to be filled. I have come up with various conditions but sadly none on them worked out,

[image]

this is my store function

```
  public function store(Request $request){
        $currentStatus = 0;

        $data = $request->validate([
            'to' => 'required',
            'date' => 'date',
            'address' => 'required',
            'reference' => 'required',
            'attention' => 'required',
            'area' => 'required',
            'project' => 'required',
            'salesman' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required'


        ]);
        \App\Contract::create($data + ['status' => $currentStatus]);
        return redirect('contracts/pendings');
```

Comment: and if the row is totaly empty is it ok ? and what did you try so far ?

Comment: Please provide some code so We can check and help

Comment: @Maraboc yeah its ok if the row is totally empty, to be honest, i have deleted the validation that I have worked on.

Comment: The easiest way to do it then is to set the required to all the fields and add a button to add rows as many as the user wants

Comment: @ChechoCZ I provided some code above

Answer (score 0):

first u need to create a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) `php artisan make:request MyControllerNameRequest`
Then in `MyControllerNameRequest` define your rules

```
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'firstField' => ['required', 'int'],
            'secondField' => ['required', 'int'],
            'thirdFied' => ['required', 'int'],
            'fourthField' => ['required', 'int'],
        ];
    }
```

after go in to your controller and add `MyControllerNameRequest` like attribute in action

```
public function store(MyControllerNameRequest $request)
{ 
      $model = Model::create($request->validated());

      return redirect()->route('route.name');
}
```

or in `some_name.blade.php` add required

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('value') }}" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the names in HTML look like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('test') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="data[0][quantity]">
    <input type="text" name="data[0][unit]">
    <input type="text" name="data[1][quantity]">
    <input type="text" name="data[1][unit]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You could try something like this in your controller.

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'data.*.quantity' => 'sometimes|required_with:data.*.unit',
    'data.*.unit' => 'sometimes|required_with:data.*.quantity',
]);
```

The `required_with` params accept multiples fields separated per comma, so you may have to pass all your fields in the validation. The `sometimes` validates only when it's passed values, so this may do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the help, @itepifanio can I ask you another question?

Comment: Sure, I'm here to help @jeffigy

Comment: I am new to laravel, @itepifanio can you please help explain to me the `data.*.quantity` or `data.*.unit`?, is it just the normal way to write names or does it have a meaning or function when it comes to the code?

Comment: You use the data.*.quantity as an abstraction for array validation. Instead of writing a for and validate each row of our array data the Laravel provides this validation for us.